Blazor with ASP.NET Core MVC project
I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project where I'm trying to add Blazor specially because we have a lot of dynamic forms inside modals, and is a pain in the ... handle all in javascript + modelstate and such....
My first attempt at adding Blazor! I tried the simplest example with a counter, and I add the component into our index.cshtml and everything works fine.
Index.cshtml
<component type="typeof(myapp.MyComponent)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

Again the counter works fine.
In another page called OurSpec.cshtml, I have a modal:
<div class="modal fade" data-bs-backdrop="static" id="modal-client" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content position-relative">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterLabel">
                    Client 
                </h5>
                <button type="button" id="btn-close-modal" class="btn-close btn btn-sm btn-circle d-flex flex-center transition-base" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body p-0">
              <component type="typeof(myapp.MyComponent)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Voltar</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnSave">Salvar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

This modal is a partial view that is called via AJAX, the counter show 0 ok but the button counterUp does not work, the method UpdateCount is not even been triggered - I have no idea why.... Can anyone help?
This is the code in MyComponent:
<h3>Classic Blazor</h3>

<span> counter: @contador</span>

<button @onclick="@UpdateCount">up count</button>

@code {
    int contador = 0;

    public void UpdateCount()
    {
        contador++;
    }
}

I have tried a lot of suggestions in gpt, internet but nothing works I'm using ASP.NET Core 8 btw

I would assume no SignalR circuit is getting created which is required, therefore no interactivity. Do you see a WebSocket connection being opened?

Yes, I have signalR, and I can see one connection

Your render mode is pre-render. You'll have to use interactive if you want the button to work.

I suggest you can use Nested components to achieve you requirement:
MyComponent.razor
<h3>Classic Blazor</h3>

<span> counter: @contador</span>

<button @onclick="@UpdateCount">up count</button>

@code {
    int contador = 0;

    public void UpdateCount()
    {
        contador++;
    }
}

PartialModal.razor
<div class="modal @ModalClass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:@ModalDisplay">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <MyComponent />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="() => Close()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@if (ShowBackdrop)
{
    <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
}


@code {


    public Guid Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string ModalDisplay = "none;";
    public string ModalClass = "";
    public bool ShowBackdrop = false;

    public void Open()
    {
        ModalDisplay = "block;";
        ModalClass = "Show";
        ShowBackdrop = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        ModalDisplay = "none";
        ModalClass = "";
        ShowBackdrop = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

EmbeddedComponent.razor
<PartialModal @ref="Modal"></PartialModal>

<button @onclick="() => Modal.Open()">Open Modal</button>

@code {
    private PartialModal Modal { get; set; }
}

OurSpec.cshtml
<component type="typeof(EmbeddedComponent)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

